# highlight the selected menu item dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke-6

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LINKS" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Links.ascx" %>

<dnn:LINKS runat="server" id="LINKS1" CssClass="MenuLink" Alignment="Horizontal"
            Level="Root" ForceLinks="False" />
```

I have the following code to produce the menu item in my dotnetnuke site. I need to change the selected menu item color or apply a different css so the user knows where they are on the site. I tried doing this using jquery by going to Page Settings and under the Page header tag. It doesn't do anything. How would I be able to highlight or apply a different css to the selected menu item?

I will appreciate for your guys help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this from the help of the url below.

[jquery to change the background color of a current page](http://learnedstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/jquery-highlighting-the-menu-item-for-the-current-page/)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late, but DNN applies the ".sel" CSS style dynamically to the currently selected menu item.

There's a PDF floating around the DNN site somewhere which details it (really hard to find), or use developer tools (F12 in IE, or Firebug in Firefox, etc) to view the styles applied to each menu item.

So add to your CSS something like:

```
.sel {
    color: #ABCDEF;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, this applies the Nav Menu skin object. Which it might be better to use as you have more styling options.